# Find first block of a file in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am storing a 500 Mb or larger video file in hdfs. Since it is larger than block size, it will get distributed. I have to collect or work first only on the first block of data(here video file), since it will only contain the sequence header. How can i do that or how to find the first block of data of a file in hadoop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It you want to read the first block, you can just get an `InputStream` from the `FileSystem` and read the bytes until it reaches your predetermined amount (example block size 64mb would be 64 * 1024 * 1024 bytes).  Here's an example (though 64mb is a lot of data. If you think the data you need is well before 64mb, just change the bytesLeft)

```
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.zookeeper.common.IOUtils;

public class TestReaderFirstBlock {

    private static final String uri = "hdfs://localhost:9000/path/to/file";
    private static int bytesLeft = 64 * 1024 * 1024;
    private static final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);

        InputStream is = fs.open(new Path(uri));
        OutputStream out = System.out;

        while (bytesLeft > 0) {
            int read = is.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(bytesLeft, buffer.length));
            if (read == -1) {
                throw new EOFException("Unexpected end of data");
            }
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            bytesLeft -= read;
        }

        IOUtils.closeStream(is);
    }
}
```

Comment: will this allocate the whole file to the local machine and do the processing? If true then we will get no benefit of hadoop. I want to process a video of size many Gbs.

Comment: Your comment is kind of contradicting. Do you or do you not want the whole file? I thought your question was that you only wanted the first block (which is default 64mb)

Comment: yes, I wanted the first block only...but...I wanted to know will this load the whole file in the local machine? If not,then this is what i wanted.